# Use the results from one method to calculate the price in another method

Tags: java, methods

I'm a beginner.
I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly I'm doing wrong. 
I have managed to get the first method working fine(calculateArea) but I don't understand why the second method isn't working(can't find symbol of area)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PaintCalculator
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double length;
      double width;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter the length >> ");
      length = keyboard.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Enter the width >> ");
      width = keyboard.nextDouble();
      keyboard.nextLine();

      calculateArea(length, width);
      calculatePrice(area);
   }

   public static double calculateArea (double length, double width)
   {
     double area;
     area = length * width;
     System.out.println(area);
     return area;

   }

  public static void calculatePrice(double area)
   {
    double gallons = area * 350;
    double price = gallons * 32;
    System.out.println(price);
   }
}
```

Sorry if this is a noob question

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working."

Comment: Please go through the [ask] to learn more about site best practices. Your title for instance should summarize your problem/error, not your frustration, and your question should contain more information describing your code, what it is supposed to be doing and what problems you're having with it and less chatty information that doesn't help us understand the code and the problem.

Comment: Yes, you've gotten an answer, and that's great, but understand that this site is not primarily a help site but rather it is supposed to be a high-quality question and answer site where the Q's and A's help all future visitors with similar problems, and this is why myself and @Zephyr are stressing the importance of your improving your question so that it meets site quality standards.

Comment: Sorry guys I apologise. I will put more thought into my questions next time.

Comment: Those are good intentions, and we thank you, but why not also improve this question as well? This will help improve the site and your question asking skills both.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to improve this question, I am a beginner so I'm not the best at explaining my problems just yet. I hope this does okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save the returned value from `calculateArea` (which is area) to double variable and the pass that to `calculatePrice`

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  double length;
  double width;

  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter the length >> ");
  length = keyboard.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("Enter the width >> ");
  width = keyboard.nextDouble();
  keyboard.nextLine();

 double area = calculateArea(length, width);
 calculatePrice(area);
 }
```

Comment: As @Hovercraft Full of else pointed please make your question as meaningful so that it might help others and also please accept answer if that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic example of how java handles data within methods. The area variable is within your calculateArea method and you are trying to use it via main and feed it into calculate price. instead assign the area to a variable and pass it in

```
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double length;
      double width;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter the length >> ");
      length = keyboard.nextDouble();
      System.out.print("Enter the width >> ");
      width = keyboard.nextDouble();
      keyboard.nextLine();

      //calculateArea(length, width);
      int area = calculateArea(length, width);
      calculatePrice(area);
      //or just directly place it in like this
      calculatePrice(calcuateArea(length, width));
   }

   public static double calculateArea (double length, double width)
   {
     double area;
     area = length * width;
     System.out.println(area);
     return area;

   }

  public static void calculatePrice(double area)
   {
    double gallons = area * 350;
    double price = gallons * 32;
    System.out.println(price);
   }
}
```